# Is mtkView(_ _: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange Size: CGSize) an OK place to update tracking areas?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, undefined-behavior, metal

Being that it would be rather inconvenient to change the class from `MTKView` to my own view, and override code to insert `updateTrackingAreas()` code, just to detect mouse moved events, would it be OK to do it instead like this?

```swift
func mtkView(_ _: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange Size: CGSize) {
    if let TrackingArea = Area {
        View.removeTrackingArea(TrackingArea)
    }
    Area = NSTrackingArea(rect: View.bounds, options: [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .mouseMoved, .activeInKeyWindow], owner: View, userInfo: nil)
    View.addTrackingArea(Area!)
    /*ProjectionMatrix = ProjectPerspective(Float(Size.width/Size.height))
    View.draw()*/
}
```

Is there an even better way to implement tracking areas in a Metal game? (I hope so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meh, just to be safe i decided to put them in updateTrackingAreas